# Unzip file in AHK

Tags: file, zip, bots, autohotkey, unzip

A want to unzip a file using script in .ahk. Somebody to help me?

tks

Unzip  ("C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Add_Polo_Plano.zip", "C:\Bots\Add_Polo_Plano")

But, it dosen't work.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It simply does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the unzip function never existed, you would have to create one by adding this:

```
Unzip(Source, Destination)
{
    RunWait PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command Expand-Archive -Path '%Source%' -DestinationPath '%Destination%';exit,%A_scriptDir%, Hide
}
```

Comment: I tried:

`Unzip ("C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\sublime_text.exe - Atalho.zip", "C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop")
{
    RunWait PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command Expand-Archive -Path 'C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\sublime_text.exe - Atalho.zip' -DestinationPath %A_Desktop%;exit,%A_scriptDir%, Hide
}`

But it dosen't work. It simply does nothing.

Comment: that's not how functions work, maybe take a look here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Functions.htm
all you need to do is paste my snippet at the end of your script and then your original code above should work